# Copy Custom Object From One Org To Another

Tags: integration, deployment, migration-tool, data-migration

Is it possible to copy one custom object from my salesforce org to another salesforce org? How?

Comment: Have you looked at change sets? Are you trying to migrate the data (a single record) or the metadata (object setup). Your tagging makes it hard to tell.

Comment: I am trying to migrate a custom object with all its existing fields and records

Answer (score 2):

I recommend working your way through some Trailhead modules, specifically in this case:

- [Deploying from Sandbox with Change Sets](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/app_deployment/app_deployment_changesets)
- [Exporting Data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/data_management/data_export)
- [Importing Data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/data_management/data_import)

Probably the most common out of the box tools to start with are `Change Sets` to move your object setup (metadata) and then `Data Loader` to move the actual records (data).

Answer (score 0):

Change sets only work between sandbox and org and will not allow transfer to another instance. You usually need to use Ant.
See this link 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm

Answer (score 0):

Would like to recommend app called Bulk Object Field Creator, it help admins to Clone all Custom Object & all of its custom fields, validation rules, Page-layouts, Record types, Reports (with Report Types & Report Folders).
Read More - [**https://bofc.io/bulk-clone-operations**](https://bofc.io/bulk-clone-operations)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).